# In ReactJS is there a way to iterate through 2 arrays and combine the 2 arrays to be grouped by the data in it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

The title might be a little confusing, but basically I'm working on a project and it requires me to have 2 array of object lists. I have a group array and a values array, I've been looking for hours for something that might work but I haven't found anything yet!

I'm needing a direction to take these 2 lists and combine them to show some stuff for the UI, I'm using ReactJS for my frontend (if that helps) and ES6. I'll try to describe the best I can for the data I need and somehow iterate it through a list that categorize from the main group and the data that matches will be sent to an array under that group and keep going until the data belongs to another group.

```
groupedObjects = {
  groupI: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'GroupI',
    array: [
       {category: 'groupI', name: 'someValue1'},
       {category: 'groupI', name: 'someValue2'},
       {category: 'groupI', name: 'someValue3'},
       {category: 'groupI', name: 'someValue4'}
]},
  groupII: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'GroupII',
    array: [
       {category: 'groupII', name: 'someValue1'},
       {category: 'groupII', name: 'someValue2'},
       {category: 'groupII', name: 'someValue3'},
       {category: 'groupII', name: 'someValue4'}
]},
  groupIII: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'GroupIII',
    array: [
       {category: 'groupIII', name: 'someValue1'},
       {category: 'groupIII', name: 'someValue2'},
       {category: 'groupIII', name: 'someValue3'},
       {category: 'groupIII', name: 'someValue4'}
]}};
```

And then somehow iterate that on a list of tables to display to the UI showing the groupI, groupII, groupIII as separate tables in each table it has the data from the array in each object.

Edit: Here's the data I needed to combine

```
const groups = [
   {
      id: 1,
      name: 'GroupI'
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      name: 'GroupII'
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      name: 'GroupIII'
   },
];

const data = [
   {
      category: 'groupI',
      name: 'someValue1'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupI',
      name: 'someValue2'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupI',
      name: 'someValue3'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupI',
      name: 'someValue4'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupII',
      name: 'someValue1'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupII',
      name: 'someValue2'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupII',
      name: 'someValue3'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupII',
      name: 'someValue4'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupIII',
      name: 'someValue1'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupIII',
      name: 'someValue2'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupIII',
      name: 'someValue3'
   },
   {
      category: 'groupIII',
      name: 'someValue4'
   }
];
```

Comment: you provided the expected output but not the input. what is the data you actually want to transform?

Comment: Please provide example of those two list you need to combine, like this we do not have enough information to help you. What is the group array and values array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide examples of those two arrays you need to combine, I will make assumption about their structures and give you one example of how you should do it:

```
 const groups = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'GroupI'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'GroupII',
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'GroupIII',
  }
];

const data = [
  { category: 'groupI', name: 'someValue1' },
  { category: 'groupI', name: 'someValue2' },
  { category: 'groupI', name: 'someValue3' },
  { category: 'groupI', name: 'someValue4' },
  { category: 'groupII', name: 'someValue1' },
  { category: 'groupII', name: 'someValue2' },
  { category: 'groupII', name: 'someValue3' },
  { category: 'groupII', name: 'someValue4' },
  { category: 'groupIII', name: 'someValue1' },
  { category: 'groupIII', name: 'someValue2' },
  { category: 'groupIII', name: 'someValue3' },
  { category: 'groupIII', name: 'someValue4' }
];

let groupedData = {};

groups.forEach(g => {
  groupedData[g.name] = {
    id: g.id,
    name: g.name,
    array: data.filter(x => x.category.toLowerCase() === g.name.toLowerCase())
  }
});

console.log(groupedData); // This will give you the output you are expecting
```

Comment: This worked! and sorry I didn't think about adding the 2 lists of data! Is there a way I can iterate through them and have them display? I tried different ways with .map, .forEach, for loops, and Object keys, and it keeps showing up as undefined or throws errors...